# "Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment."

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Since I have updated Jupyter Notebook to 6.4.11, and `matplotlib` to 3.5.1, I get this warning:

`Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.`

What is the font cache? Is it safe to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try deleting the .json file on the cache directory and restarting the kernel, the cache folder is given by:

```
import matplotlib as mpl    
print(mpl.get_cachedir())
```

This recreated the cache file for me.